# Can I ignore CORS in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension for site A that displays data from site B (example.com) for each page. When I try to do:

```js
fetch('example.com')
```

In my Chrome extension with this in my manifest.json:

```json
    "permissions": [
        "*://example.com/*"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://example.com/*",
    ]
```

I still get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Is it possible to tell Chrome to let me make CORS requests from the extension or is there no special permission for extensions? Do I have to host a proxy? I have no control over either site.

Comment: Manifestv3 will make it hard, but yes it's possible, I know I was doing similar with tampermonkey for cross-browser compliance.